# Creating CSS3 shapes round corner?

Tags: css, shapes

I know i can create in CSS a lot of round corners, but i have never created something like this

[image]

I don't need styling for fonts, and heading only for left corner, it is possible to make it like this?

I know i can create moon like this, maybe this is the way?

```
#moon { 
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
border-radius: 50%; 
box-shadow: 15px 15px 0 0 red; 
}
```

I think it has to be before pseudo class?
Any idea how to make it like my picture?

Comment: beyond my CCS knowledge could you not have 2 DIVs inline one the blue rectangle and the other the white curve space which overlaps on the blue to give the effect?

Comment: Can you please write answer but it will be better to be in :before

Comment: I was playing but the answer seems good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you want something like this

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8eq814pv/)**

just create and element with `:before`, and make it oval.

to make it oval you need to set `border-radius:100%;` and the element should have a rectangle form... not a square form.

and then some minor position adjustments.

for this solution to work the `background-color` of the container where your element is situated ( in this case `body` ) needs to be the same as the `background-color` of the `:before` element

```css
body {
  background:#fff;
}

h2 { 

color:#fff;
font-size:20px;
padding:10px;
width:200px;
text-align:right;
background:blue;
text-transform:uppercase;
position:relative;

}

h2:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  background:#fff;
  height:120%;
  width:50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left:-25px;
  top:-10%;
}
```

```html
<h2>
Predictions
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `radial-gradient` for `background` property of your element without any extra elements or pseudo-elements:

```css
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;

  line-height: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;

  background: radial-gradient(circle 26px at 0% 50%, transparent, transparent 25px, #0000ff);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">Predictions</div>
```

More over, you can play with parameters of `radial-gradient` to get any required arc:

```css
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;

  line-height: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;

  background: radial-gradient(circle 41px at -13% 50%, transparent, transparent 40px, #0000ff);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">Predictions</div>
```

Please look at the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/247wz166/).

Comment: @Hughzi Thanks for your edit, it seems it was rejected because of my own edit I did right after you.